# **On my new bike** here describes the verb(get) or adverb(quickly)?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I can get there more quickly **on my new bike.**

Are there any trick to find it out???

Comment: **Are there any tricks?** I would say it modifies **get there**. No trick, just commonsense.

Comment: But on book it's written that the prepositional phrase is modifying "more quickly".

Comment: Book?  what book, If you are confused because of something in a book it is a good idea to mention the book in the question.

Comment: @JamesK farlex complete English grammar book

Comment: @JamesK it's mentioned that Here, on my new bike describes the adverb more quickly, answering the question “How?” or “In what manner?” It could also seem that the prepositional phrase is describing the verb get, but the information in the prepositional phrase is specific to getting there quickly. (Can u explain me now)

Comment: Ah, this https://languageadvisor.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Complete-English-Grammar-Rules-PDFDrive-.pdf  I'd tend to disagree, I'd say it answering the question "how can I get there more quickly", and so modifies the whole expression "I can get there more quickly".  One of the real grammarians my be able to clarify with CEGL references.